# C/C++ Registry Help

Tags: c++, c, resources

I am programming an mp3 application, and I have it so it starts on start up. However when looking at it in msconfig it says manufacturer is unknown. How can I make it say "daxsoft"?

Is there a a way to do this without a .rc file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a version section to the .rc file included in your project (and add a .rc file if you don't have one already).

In side the .rc file you need an RT_VERSION block which lets you specify the files version, company, etc.

This information is processed by the resource compiler (rc.exe) and included in the final exe.  Visual Studio will handle this for you automatically if you add the .rc file to the project.

For an old, but still accurate overview of the process see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194804.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from your .exe file, and you need to sign that:

http://blogs.msdn.com/secureapps/archive/2007/01/25/code-signing.aspx